# Why set the RequestInitializationTimeout property?

Tags: .net, wcf

What is the HttpTransportElement's RequestInitializationTimeout about? MSDN says:

> Gets or sets the timespan that specifies how long the request initialization has to complete before timing out.

What exactly is "request initialization"? Why might I want to set this property?

Answer (score 9):

There is no clear documentation regarding [`RequestInitializationTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.configuration.httptransportelement.requestinitializationtimeout?view=netframework-4.8#System_ServiceModel_Configuration_HttpTransportElement_RequestInitializationTimeout).

There is a comment inside the source code of [`SharedHttpTransportManager.IsCompatible`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/SharedHttpTransportManager.cs#L43) regarding `RequestInitializationTimeout` checking:

> ```
> // We are NOT checking the RequestInitializationTimeout here since the HttpChannelListener should be handle them
> // individually. However, some of the scenarios might be impacted, e.g., if we have one endpoint with high RequestInitializationTimeout
> // and the other is just normal, the first endpoint might be occupying all the receiving loops, then the requests to the normal endpoint
> // will experience timeout issues. The mitigation for this issue is that customers should be able to increase the MaxPendingAccepts number.
> ```

If we check the [`TimeoutException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timeoutexception?view=netcore-3.1) that it assigns to the `requestException` that is passed along with the `HttpRequestContext.SetMessage(message, requestException)` inside the [`OnParseComplete`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L269), we can see:

```cs
new TimeoutException(SR.GetString(
    SR.RequestInitializationTimeoutReached,
    this.HttpRequestContext.Listener.RequestInitializationTimeout,
    "RequestInitializationTimeout",
    typeof(HttpTransportBindingElement).Name))
```

and the regarding [`SR.RequestInitializationTimeoutReached`](https://github.com/micbelgique/John-Doe/blob/master/Unity/Devcamp/WindowsStoreApp/Devcamp/obj/x86/Debug/FxResources.System.Private.ServiceModel.SR.resw#L6375) [`System.Private.ServiceModel`](https://github.com/micbelgique/John-Doe/blob/master/Unity/Devcamp/WindowsStoreApp/Devcamp/obj/x86/Debug/FxResources.System.Private.ServiceModel.SR.resw) exception message is:

```
The initialization process of the request message timed out after {0}. To increase this quota, use the '{1}' property on the '{2}'.
```

that will be formatted to something like this:

```
The initialization process of the request message timed out after 00:00:10. To increase this quota, use the 'RequestInitializationTimeout' property on the 'HttpTransportBindingElement'.
```

### tl;dr

If we follow the source code, we can find it's usage inside [`EmptyHttpPipeline`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L211).

### In contructor [`EmptyHttpPipeline.EmptyHttpPipeline`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L217)

If there is a `RequestInitializationTimeout` `TimeSpan` (*and not the [default `00:00:00`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/TransportDefaults.cs#L348) that disables it*), an [`IOThreadTimer`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ServiceModel.Internals/System/Runtime/IOThreadTimer.cs,35) is set with the `dueTime` set to the `TimeSpan` ticks, the [`OnRequestInitializationTimeout`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L316) `Action` callback and `this` (*the actual `EmptyHttpPipeline` object*) as the `callbackState`.

```cs
if (this.httpRequestContext.Listener.RequestInitializationTimeout != HttpTransportDefaults.RequestInitializationTimeout)
{
    this.requestInitializationTimer = new IOThreadTimer(onRequestInitializationTimeout, this, false);
    this.requestInitializationTimer.Set(this.httpRequestContext.Listener.RequestInitializationTimeout);
}
```

### When it's being checked?

It's checked when the [`EmptyHttpPipeline.OnParseComplete`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L269) method is being called by trying to cancel the [`requestInitializationTimer`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L214). If there is a timer and it's being previously canceled or overdue, it creates a `TimeoutException` that it assigns to the `requestException` that it's passed to the `HttpPipeline.HttpRequestContext.SetMessage` along with the `message`:

```cs
protected override void OnParseComplete(Message message, Exception requestException)
{
    if (!this.CancelRequestInitializationTimer() && requestException == null)
    {
        requestException = FxTrace.Exception.AsError(new TimeoutException(SR.GetString(
                                SR.RequestInitializationTimeoutReached,
                                this.HttpRequestContext.Listener.RequestInitializationTimeout,
                                "RequestInitializationTimeout",
                                typeof(HttpTransportBindingElement).Name)));
    }

    this.HttpRequestContext.SetMessage(message, requestException);
}
```

The [`OnParseComplete`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L269) method is being called inside [`EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L903) using the [`HandleParseIncomingMessage`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L896) `AsyncCallback` inside the [`EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.End`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L891) method. The [`EnqueueMessageAsyncResult`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L868) object is created when invoking [`EmptyHttpPipeline.BeginProcessInboundRequest`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L241) and it terminates inside [`EmptyHttpPipeline.EndProcessInboundRequest`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L251).

#### [`BeginProcessInboundRequest`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L241) and [`EndProcessInboundRequest`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L251)

```cs
internal override IAsyncResult BeginProcessInboundRequest(
    ReplyChannelAcceptor replyChannelAcceptor,
    Action dequeuedCallback,
    AsyncCallback callback,
    object state)
{
    this.TraceBeginProcessInboundRequestStart();
    return new EnqueueMessageAsyncResult(replyChannelAcceptor, dequeuedCallback, this, callback, state);
}

internal override void EndProcessInboundRequest(IAsyncResult result)
{
    // It will trigger HandleParseIncomingMessage AsyncCallback,
    // that will call CompleteParseAndEnqueue
    EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.End(result);
    this.TraceProcessInboundRequestStop();
}
```

#### [`EnqueueMessageAsyncResult.CompleteParseAndEnqueue`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L903)

```cs
void CompleteParseAndEnqueue(IAsyncResult result)
{
    using (DiagnosticUtility.ShouldUseActivity ? ServiceModelActivity.BoundOperation(this.CallbackActivity) : null)
    {
        Exception requestException;
        Message message = this.pipeline.EndParseIncomingMesssage(result, out requestException);
        if ((message == null) && (requestException == null))
        {
            throw FxTrace.Exception.AsError(
                    new ProtocolException(
                        SR.GetString(SR.MessageXmlProtocolError),
                        new XmlException(SR.GetString(SR.MessageIsEmpty))));
        }

        // Here the EmptyHttpPipeline.OnParseComplete is being invoked
        this.pipeline.OnParseComplete(message, requestException);
        this.acceptor.Enqueue(this.pipeline.HttpRequestContext, this.dequeuedCallback, true);
    }
}
```

### How it's being checked and canceled?

It's being checked using the [`CancelRequestInitializationTimer`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L293) method and if there is no timer set, it just returns true; if it's previously canceled it returns false, else it calls `IOThreadTimer.Cancel` method to check and return true if it's canceled or false if the timer is overdue.

#### [`EmptyHttpPipeline.CancelRequestInitializationTimer`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L293)

```cs
protected bool CancelRequestInitializationTimer()
{
    if (this.requestInitializationTimer == null)
    {
        return true;
    }

    if (this.requestInitializationTimerCancelled)
    {
        return false;
    }

    bool result = this.requestInitializationTimer.Cancel();
    this.requestInitializationTimerCancelled = true;

    return result;
}
```

### What is actually being canceled?

Inside the [`OnRequestInitializationTimeout`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L316) method, we can see that it cancels the `HttpPipeline` which aborts the [`HttpPipeline.httpRequestContext`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L22):

#### [`EmptyHttpPipeline.OnRequestInitializationTimeout`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L316)

```cs
static void OnRequestInitializationTimeout(object obj)
{
    Fx.Assert(obj != null, "obj should not be null.");
    HttpPipeline thisPtr = (HttpPipeline)obj;
    thisPtr.Cancel();
}
```

#### [`HttpPipeline.Cancel`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L134)

```cs
public virtual void Cancel()
{
  this.httpRequestContext.Abort();
}
```

### When do we get an [`EmptyHttpPipeline`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L211) object?

We get an [`EmptyHttpPipeline`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L211) if we set `transportIntegrationHandler = null` using the static [`HttpPipeline.CreateHttpPipeline`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L74) that accepts a [`TransportIntegrationHandler`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelListener.cs#L1471) and there is no [`HttpRequestContext.HttpMessagesSupported`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpRequestContext.cs#L48):

```cs
public static HttpPipeline CreateHttpPipeline(HttpRequestContext httpRequestContext, TransportIntegrationHandler transportIntegrationHandler, bool isWebSocketTransport)
{
    if (transportIntegrationHandler == null)
    {
        Fx.Assert(!isWebSocketTransport, "isWebSocketTransport should be false if there's no HTTP message handler existing.");

        if (httpRequestContext.HttpMessagesSupported)
        {
            return new HttpMessageSupportedHttpPipeline(httpRequestContext);
        }

        return new EmptyHttpPipeline(httpRequestContext);
    }

    return NormalHttpPipeline.CreatePipeline(httpRequestContext, transportIntegrationHandler, isWebSocketTransport);
}
```

The [`CreateHttpPipeline`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpPipeline.cs#L74) is called on [`HttpRequestContext.InitializeHttpPipeline`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpRequestContext.cs#L170):

#### [`HttpRequestContext.InitializeHttpPipeline`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpRequestContext.cs#L170)

```cs
public void InitializeHttpPipeline(TransportIntegrationHandler transportIntegrationHandler)
{
    this.httpPipeline = HttpPipeline.CreateHttpPipeline(this, transportIntegrationHandler, this.IsWebSocketRequest);
}
```

which is called on [`HttpRequestContext requestContext`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelListener.cs#L1237) (*passed in [`HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelListener.cs#L1229) constructor*) inside [`HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult<TListenerChannel>.ProcessHttpContextAsync`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelListener.cs#L1284) using [`HttpChannelListener<TListenerChannel>.transportIntegrationHandler`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelListener.cs#L827)

#### [`HttpContextReceivedAsyncResult<TListenerChannel>.ProcessHttpContextAsync`](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.ServiceModel/System/ServiceModel/Channels/HttpChannelListener.cs#L1221)

```cs
AsyncCompletionResult ProcessHttpContextAsync()
{
    bool abort = false;
    try
    {
        this.context.InitializeHttpPipeline(this.listener.transportIntegrationHandler);
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

### Conclusion

All these leave us with the conclusion that when a `HttpPipeline` is created without a `TransportIntegrationHandler` and no `HttpMessagesSupported` for the `HttpRequestContext`, then the new `EmptyHttpPipeline` object will have a timeout (*if `RequestInitializationTimeout` is set*) for  `BeginProcessInboundRequest`/`EndProcessInboundRequest` and set an exception when setting the message using `EmptyHttpPipeline.HttpRequestContext.SetMessage` inside `EmptyHttpPipeline.OnParseComplete`.